# Updating row based on other´s row data

Tags: r

I am comfortable updating columns based on other´s column value, like below:

```
data[,"col"] <- data[,"col_A"] + data[,"col_B"]
```

Notice that all computation done above are based on values from the same current row.
However, I am trying to update columns based on values from **previous** row.

```
for( i in 2:nrow(data)) ){
    data[i,"col"] <- data[i-1,"col_A"] + data[i-1,"col_B"]
}
```

How can I do this using just one command without the "for" iteration, just like the first one?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

Based on comment from @r2evans, that pointed `dplyr::lag` function, I could solve using this code:

```
data[,"col"] <- lag(data[,"col_A"]) + lag(data[,"col_B"])
```

I can handle directly the `NA` that takes place in the first row. 
Thanks @r2evans :-)

Comment: Have you looked at `dplyr::lag` or `data.table::shift`?

Comment: What do you intend to happen for the first row? Just skip it?

Comment: No problem. I can handle it directly, depending on the context logic. An ifelse can solve this.

Comment: BTW: you don't need the `dplyr` package just for this function, it's easy enough to write your own "cheap" version: `mylag <- function(x,n=1,default=NA) c(rep(default,n),x[-(length(x)+1-seq_len(n))])`. It does no error checking (for instance, `n<1` fails), but it might be functional *enough*.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid `for` loop by using `rowSums`:

`data[-1, "col"] <- rowSums(data[-nrow(data), c("col_A", "col_B")])`

Comment: The sum is a particular case and I used it just as an example. In fact the expression is more general and `lag()` can be also used for doing sum too. Thanks!